# JMS Client and JMS Server timestamp is different

Tags: timestamp, jms, activemq-classic

I use ActiveMQ as JMS Server and I want to send non-persistent message which expire after some seconds because I don't want to queue to many messages if e.g. the consuming client is down. (Is there a best pratice?)

Problem is if JMS Server timestamp differs with JMS Client timestamp. Is there a nice way to get the JMS Servers timestamp? Or is the ActiveMQ [timestampingPlugin](http://activemq.apache.org/timestampplugin.html) the "best" way of fixing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The TimeStampBrokerPlugin was implemented to solve problems like this.  If you can't sync up the clocks via NTP then having the broker use its own time will ensure that it doesn't immediately timeout a Message or keep it around way to long.

I'm not sure what you're asking in regards to getting the broker's timestamp, but in general using the Broker plugin is you best option when dealing with out of sync clocks.

Comment: Ok, so there is no way to get the server's timestamp with a **system** queue or something like that? I don't really like it but I works for me.